# How to get only first rows from table ordered by dublicating values in column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table looks like:

```
id | size | price | date
0  | 30   | 800   | 2021-10-01
1  | 30   | 900   | 2021-10-02
2  | 32   | 700   | 2021-09-11
3  | 30   | 800   | 2021-09-21
4  | 32   | 800   | 2021-09-01
5  | 32   |  0    | 2021-10-03
```

And i need to get the last updated prices of size <= 'size' to check it for zero and get first non-zero value. I try to sort table by size desc, date desc, but can't take only first rows with dublicating sizes.

```
SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT * 
            FROM `prices` 
                WHERE model_id = '269'
                    AND partner_id = '0'
                    AND size <= '32'
                  AND    date_time <= '2021-10-19' 
                 ORDER BY size DESC, date_time DESC
    ) AS t_1 
        GROUP BY size
        LIMI 1
```

does not help. The first result what i want is

```
id | size | price | date
5  | 32   |  0    | 2021-10-03
1  | 30   | 900   | 2021-10-02
```

then i want to get 900.

Answer (score 0):

Using exists logic we can try:

```sql
SELECT p1.*
FROM prices p1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM prices p2
                  WHERE p2.size = p1.size AND p2.date > p1.date);
```

More typically, on MySQL 8+, we would handle this using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY size ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM prices
)

SELECT id, size, price, date
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

One advantage of using `ROW_NUMBER` is that should there be two or more latest records tied on the same date, we can simply add another sorting level to the `ORDER BY` clause to break the tie.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM prices p
WHERE 
    size <= '32' 
    AND date LIKE (SELECT max(date) from prices where size = p.size and price <> 0)
```